# Why does Rust cargo rebuild some packages a second time?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Why does cargo recompile a second time? Is this an error in some package, like memchr?

Can I trust the first build to be the same as the second?

`build.sh` is just a call to `RUSTFLAGS="-C linker=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" cargo build --release --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --manifest-path init_pi/Cargo.toml`

Could it have something to do with having to specify the linker, even though I have specified the target? Not sure why target type is not enough.

```
$ ./build.sh
   Compiling memchr v2.3.3
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.18
   Compiling json v0.12.4
   Compiling thread_local v1.0.1
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.13
   Compiling regex v1.3.9
   Compiling init_pi v0.1.0 (.../init_pi)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 10.61s
$ ./build.sh
   Compiling memchr v2.3.3
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.13
   Compiling regex v1.3.9
   Compiling init_pi v0.1.0 (.../init_pi)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 8.24s
$ ./build.sh
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.15s
```

Comment: `init_pi` depends on `regex` which depends on `aho-corasick` which depends on `memchr`. It's possible that `memchr` is the only culprit here. `memchr` does have a `build.rs` that could confuse cargo, but it seems reasonable, and doesn't have any relevant issue on GitHub.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, could you confirm that you see this same behaviour when invoking the `cargo` command directly rather than through `build.sh`.

Comment: same behavior running cargo directly, same md5sum before and after so I guess binary is fine after first build, just a bit sad having to wait for the "rebuild" when it should not be needed

Answer (score 1):

As a more general answer, as of [Cargo 1.68 (2023-03-09)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cargo-168-2023-03-09), Cargo will show some information about why things were rebuilt when verbose mode is enabled (e.g. via `cargo build --verbose`).

Trivial example (rebuilding due to source file being changed):

```
Dirty mycrate v0.0.11-dev (/repos/mycrate): the file `src/main.rs` has changed (1687720677.139087400s, 32m 47s after last build at 1687718710.000000000s)
```

More tricky example I just had to look into (rebuilding due to a rounding error in the file system timestamp, resulting in Cargo thinking a file generated by build.rs was modified just 478 ms after the last build):

```
Dirty mycrate v0.0.11-dev (/repos/mycrate): the file `target/debug/build/mycrate-b99d3c44d24f0f1c/out/src/generated.rs` has changed (1687730366.478512500s, 478512500ns after last build at 1687730366.000000000s)
```

I believe this is [Cargo bug #12060](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/12060) (the problem would also be solved by [#6529](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6529) but that seems to have stalled). I solved most of my spurious rebuilds by changing my build.rs script to only write out the generated file if its contents has changed.

If `--verbose` is insufficient, [#2904](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2904) also suggests the command

```
CARGO_LOG=cargo::core::compiler::fingerprint=trace cargo build
```

but that debug output is very dense and not terribly accessible.